# What is the motivation behind this proof, any list of vector with length n+1 in the span of an independent list of vector with length n is dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

[image]
[image]

Although I can understand each step of the proof, the process seems random to be and I do not understand why in each step, the author choose to do the manipulation this way. I have read the proof for about three times but I cannot repeat the proof on my own. Where I do not understand the motivation starts at the discussion of Case 1 and ends at the end of the proof. Here is the proof from Apostol Calculus Volume 2.
If this proof is too intricate, can you provide a simpler proof that requires only knowledge of linear space, subspace, span and independence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now. This is a process called Gaussian elimination.